# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" on each npm command

Tags: node.js, npm

npm installation broke after setting a config parameter:

i.e. I set the cafile parameter of npm config, now every npm command returns this error:

> Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
>       at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22)
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
>       at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
>       at finalize (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:189:14)
>       at Conf.afterCARead (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\load-cafile.js:14:14)
>   C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205
>     if (npm.config.get('json')) {
>                    ^

it seems like I've broken the npm configuration by doing 
npm config set cafile ""

Answer (score 7):

Delete the file /Users/username/.npmrc.

I reinstalled node multiple times with and without nvm but this is the only thing that fixed the permissions issue.

Comment: I deleted `C:\Users\myuser\.npmrc` then uninstalled and reinstalled Node.js 10 again on windows using the installer. This worked for me.

Comment: I deleted the `C:\Users\myuser\.npmrc` and did not need to re-install Node and it worked. Thank you!!

Comment: I have no `~/.npmrc`

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to edit the npm config file manualy.
On Windows they are located here:

userconfig :

```
C:\Users\myuser\.npmrc
```

globalconfig :

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc
```

Comment: I had to remove the content from .npmrc file, i had the same issue i incorrectly issed the following command in windows command prompt  " npm config set cafile "C:" it didn't throw any error. 

after clearing the content, i issed npm -version it worked.